# Place two div, a middle and a bottom, in a form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I place in a responsive form of div, a central and a bottom; I inserted the following code:

```
<link href="../css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../css/splashscreen.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body class="container container-table">
    <div class="text-center col-md-12 col-md-offset-12 vertical-center-row">
        <img class="img-responsive center-block imageCenterContentFirst" src="../images/disegno11.svg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-12 vertical-bottom-row">
        <img class="img-responsive center-block imageCenterContentSecond" src="../images/logo_macnil_zucchetti.svg" />
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, .container-table {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100% !important;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

}
.container-table {
    display: table;
}
.vertical-center-row {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 50%;
}
.vertical-bottom-row {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.imageCenterContentFirst {
    width: 100%;
}
```

The two `div` do not align as I want, but that seem to appear side by side, as seen in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNSVL.png). Where the red is the first image, the purple is the second image, while the white part with the other are the two `div`, which should be one below the other.

I can not understand why one does not go under the other.

Comment: A working demo in of your code in jsfiddle and an image of what you're trying to achieve would be helpful. Also, are you supporting IE9 and below?

Comment: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/qbhb5qfu/) It supports ie9 up, but also the the mobile. thank you

Comment: can you support demo link also an image for what you want to get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the two divs displayed one above the other, try using display: table-row instead of table-cell, as direct children of display: table;. Also you had set one of the divs to 50% width.

```
.container-table {
    display: table;
}
.vertical-center-row {
    display: table-row;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background:red;
}
.vertical-bottom-row {
    display: table-row;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    background:violet;
}
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/lundmn/apqhhho3/2/)